# Including Java classes and running them during runtime

Tags: java, reflection, dynamic-loading

I have a Java project that needs a "addon" interface. I was thinking about loading some kind of class files having default methods like `initialize()` and `shutdown()` that will be called after the class has been loaded into the application. Is this the way to do it? How would I approach this problem?

Comment: Are you asking about dynamically loading classes or defining behavior for initialization for a class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [Class](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) class, specifically the [forName](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)) method, which allows you to reference a class by name. Any class in the path can be loaded like this. Whether *reloading* is possible I don't know.

In any case, each class that you want to dynamically load would have to implement your custom `AddOn` interface, thus implementing `initialize` and `shutdown`.

Comment: This worked! I don't know if this is the "correct" way to do it, and I'm happy for feedback. Keep in mind that this is only for loading one class:
        Class classfoo = Class.forName("addonclass");
        Object foo = null;
        Object[] foo2 = null;
        classfoo.getMethod("initialize").invoke(foo, foo2);

Comment: Happy to hear it works! Myself I'm also interested in feedback about the "correct" way. I have the feeling a more elegant way exists...

Comment: "I have a feeling a more elegant way exists." No, this is the documented correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you will need a [`ClassLoader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html); you can get the current one with `getClass().getClassLoader()`, but then your addon classes must be in the classpath. You'll probably want to create a custom classloader that searches your addon directory.

Once you've got the `ClassLoader`, you can use it to [load a class](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass(java.lang.String)). This gives you a [`Class`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object; you can then use reflection to call the `initialize()` method if it is present.

Comment: You only need your own class loader if you want a non-standard way to load the class. If the class exists as a ".class" file in a folder on the class path, the standard class loader will do it.

If you want to, say, download the class from the Internet behind the scenes, then you'd need a custom class loader.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at something more sophisticated, you can try : http://jpf.sourceforge.net.

*... JPF provides a runtime engine that dynamically discovers and loads "plug-ins".A plug-in is a structured component that describes itself to JPF using a "manifest". ...*

Answer (score 0):

Another nice way to realize addons is [java.util.Serviceloader](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html). Have a look at the javadocs, they explain the principle.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class SomeClass { 
    static {
        System.out.println("Being called with the class is loaded");
        initialize();
    }
    static void initialize(){}
}
```

Is that your question?

Comment: Nice :) But how can I load and run a class from a file? The class won't come with the application, the user will "download" the addon and add it to the "addons" folder. The application will load all the addons when started.

Comment: Yeap. I actually didn't quite catch what your question was in first place. Class.forName is pretty much the way to go.